# Java - lock acquisition on get method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, queue

I have recently studied some concurrent classes in Java, such as `PriorityBlockingQueue` and here is the relevant piece of code:

```
public E peek() {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    E result;
    try {
        result = size > 0 ? (E) queue[0] : null;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Let's consider rewriting this a bit (for a purpose of this question), given that queue[0] is either set or null, therefore becoming simply `return queue[0]`. Now, I am not sure that in this scenario lock acquisition is actually necessary... Could it be non thread safe without a lock due to some edge-case compiler optimizations?

Answer (score 2):

The locking is to ensure external consistency in relation to the order in time that methods on a `PriorityBlockingQueue` are called.

Say `thread-offer` calls `offer` before `thread-peek` calls `peek` - the lock ensures that `thread-peek` is blocked until `thread-offer` has completed, at which point the value `thread-offer` added, can be returned by `thread-peak` - the logs might look like this:

```
2013-03-12 10:40:00.000 [thread-offer] INFO offering value X
2013-03-12 10:40:00.001 [thread-peak] INFO peeking value
2013-03-12 10:40:00.002 [thread-offer] INFO offered value X
2013-03-12 10:40:00.003 [thread-peak] INFO peeked value X
```

The alternative, where the `peek` method isn't locking could allow `null` to be returned, despite an earlier call to `offer` - the logs might look like this:

```
2013-03-12 10:50:00.000 [thread-offer] INFO offering value X
2013-03-12 10:50:00.001 [thread-peak] INFO peeking value
2013-03-12 10:50:00.002 [thread-peak] INFO peeked value null
2013-03-12 10:50:00.003 [thread-offer] INFO offered value X
```

These logs are a little contrived, but hopefully demonstrate the point, that the operations should be atomic.

Comment: But the queue has length of e.g. 10 and does not get shrunk by any of the methods is it? SImply calling` queue[0]` on a queue that has all elements null will not throw any exception

Comment: And I assume for this purpose that the `queue.length > 0`

Comment: @struggler - jumped the start with that answer, I've modified it, to what I now believe to be correct

Answer (score 1):

Consider another thread calling `remove()` at the same time. If `peek()` is not locked, this can happen:

```
peeker              remover
------              -------
                    ret = queue[0]
return queue[0] <-- BUG
                    queue[0] <- queue[1]
                    return ret
```

You have an inconsistency; as the peeker can execute concurrently with the remover, it doesn't see the result of the remove operation. It returns the wrong result. Which means the queue is not thread safe anymore.

Comment: I cannot see why this is a bug: peek returns the first element of the queue, which is what we want. We cannot assure when we call peek() that a remove() is being called and executed just before the lock()

Comment: Except here what is returned is in fact `queue[1]`.

Comment: No, it returns the current queue[0], which was previously in queue[1]. If another thread is removing elements this one cannot ensure what will find when asks for the next element to be processed, even with the lock.

Comment: Now you're right, I'm going to update my answer because it can mislead

Comment: Well, even with the locks you get one thread to win the lock and execute, so the peeker either sees the remove or not. However, the semantics is stronger - IF the remove operation is started, then it will fully complete, before any other thread will see the updates of it. BUT, maybe the semantics of struggler are not like that, i.e. the peeker will read SOME value, which might be the value just ABOUT TO be removed, which is still a snapshot of some state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CopyOnWriteArrayList or look at the implementation of that class. There you have only synchronisation, if the list is modified. But be aware that you can read the list, even if some other thread is removing or adding an element. You always work with a copy of the current list. The PriorityBlockingQueue is locking every public method. So this is can stop the threads from efficiently working, if you have many threads.

Consider also this implementation(see also AtomicInteger). Every Thread can work with a local copy of PriorityQueue and therefore you do not need synchronisation any more. AtomicReference is not so expensive like locking:

```
public class PriorityQueueUpdater {

private AtomicReference<PriorityQueue<String>> priorityQueueRef= new AtomicReference<>  (null);

public PriorityQueue<String> getPriorityQueueRef() {
    for (;;) {
        PriorityQueue<String> current = priorityQueueRef.get();
        PriorityQueue<String> next = priorityQueueRef.get();
        if (priorityQueueRef.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}

    public void setPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue<String> priorityQueue) {
        this.priorityQueueRef.set(priorityQueue);
    }

}
```

PS: with AtomicMarkableReference you can also combine 2 variables with one snap. In your example it would be size and the queue.